# Is the pre-image of a path-connected set path connected as well?

Tags: general-topology

Given that $f$ is a continuous function and $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. If $V$ is path connected does this imply $f^{-1}(V)$ is path connected as well?

I suspect no, but I'm not sure what a good example is to give if it's false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no.

Consider $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ as given by $f(x) = x^2$.  $V = [1,4]$ is path connected, but $f^{-1}(V)$ is not.

Comment: Is $f^{-1}(V)$ equal to $[-2,-1] \cap [1,2]$ so by $\text{IVT}$ we can say there isn't a continuous function that joins say -1 and 2?

Comment: That would do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the simplest possible example:

Suppose $V$ consists of a single point and $U$ consists of two points, and consider the *only* function from $U$ to $V$ ...

Note that this implies a very general result. If $(X, \tau)$ is a topological space and $x, y\in X$ are distinct, then either $U=\{x, y\}$, $V=\{x\}$ is a counterexample or $\{x, y\}$ is path-connected. So the example above works in every $T_1$ space with at least two points.

Conversely, we do need a separation assumption: there are $T_0$ spaces in which *every* subset is path connected.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds rather unlikely. Could there be some "two-to-one map"
where the inverse image of $V$ would be a union of two separated sets
each homeomorphic to $V$? You could try a generically "two-to-one map"
such as $x\mapsto x^2$ on $\Bbb R$ and see if you can find suitable $U$ and $V$.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure about how to tackle the question originally, but I see now.