# Provide an example where $S$ is not path connected, $f:S\longrightarrow T$ is continuous and Im$f$ is path connected.

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{Im}$

Provide an example where $S$ is not path connected, $f:S\longrightarrow T$ is continuous and $\Im{f}$ is path connected.

Let $S = [0,1] \cup \{2\} \subset \mathbb{R}$, $T=\mathbb{R}$. Let $f:S \longrightarrow T$ be given by,
$$f(s) =
 \begin{cases} 
      s & 0\leq s \leq 1 \\
      s-1 & s=2 
   \end{cases}
$$

Then $f$ is continuous and $\Im{f}=[0,1]$ is obviously path connected.

Is this example correct? Are there simpler examples?

Comment: Is your function continous? Maybe check this out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319240/is-the-pre-image-of-a-path-connected-set-path-connected-as-well

Comment: Let $f(x) = x$ on $(0,2)$ and $f(x) = x-3$ on $(3,5)$.

Comment: Does the openness of the sets in the domain of $f$ make a difference?

Comment: Not in my example.

Comment: Are S and T supposed to be metric spaces? Topological spaces?

Comment: This was not specified in the question but we have not covered metric or topological spaces yet, so S and T are implied to be subsets of Euclidean space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler example: take $f$ constant.

Answer (score 2):

Take $Y=\Bbb R$, usual topology (or any path-connected space), $X=\Bbb R$ in the discrete topology (totally disconnected as always), $f(x)=x$. Any function on a discrete space is continuous.

Comment: Is this example similar to letting $X= \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @pyridoxal_trigeminus No, a countable set will hardly ever be path-connected. So the only thing I can up with as $Y$ is $\Bbb Z$ in the indiscrete/trivial topology. Pretty boring.